# How to get the object's position in the array?

Tags: php

My array:

```
$array = array(
    'test' => new Object(2),
    'two' => new Object(22),
    'other' => new Object(12),
    'five' => new Object(23),
    'next' => new Object(42),
);
```

How can I get position in this array?

I have variable:

```
$object = Object(12);
```

So I would like receive:

```
$position = 3; //or 2 if we number from 0
```

array_keys is not working in this example...

Comment: What result do you want when the search value is not found?  When you use Philipp's method, unmatched search objects will fire a `Notice` and return `1` -- not great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$position = array_search($object, array_values($array), true) + 1;`

[array_search manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), [array_values manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

With `array_values` you remove the keys and get an indexed array instead. Because you want the position and not the index of the element you need to add 1 to it.

[Working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4acc81da303c9466d2665b0e01ef19327a0e64c8)

Comment: @kranthi Can you specify your question please?

Comment: respective to above ques and ur ans